# blogger multiple custom domains?

Tags: blogger

I have two domains I'd like to use for the same blogger page (`some-example.bloger.com`) on two sites.

One is `blog.example.ca`, the other domain is `blog.meta-example.com`

Both should end up displaying the same blog, except I can't find a way to put two blogs together.

Other than forwarding the sub-domain to go to a new site, do I have any way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can know [how to use own sitename with Blogger Service](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=58317), you can imagine  to create *CNAME on CNAME*, as result - both names will be served by the same Blogger blog.

You have only test will sites save own domain in links or not (I'm not sure in handling of HOST request by G)

Comment: That's a pretty cool idea, I'm going to give it a shot. I won't know for a few days, but it sounds good.

Comment: Don't forget configure some parts from blog's settings (I'm not sure is it needed, but...) and AFAICS possibility to have only one external URL for blog presented

Answer (score -1):

Are they on the same server? Because if so you can modify your `turbopanel.conf` via SSH

Mine is located in `etc/httpd/conf.d/turbopanel.conf` but yours may differ.

It should look something like this:

```
NameVirtualHost 123.45.67.89:80

<VirtualHost 123.45.67.89:80>
    ServerAdmin "webmaster@site1.com"
    ServerName site1.com
    ServerAlias www.site1.com
    MIMEMagicFile /dev/null
    CustomLog logs/site1.com_access_log "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\""
    ErrorLog logs/site1.com_error_log

    DocumentRoot "/home/site1/public_html"
    <Directory "/home/site1/public_html">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    Alias /usage "/home/site1/public_html/usage"
    <Location /usage>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost 123.45.67.89:80

<VirtualHost 123.45.67.89:80>
    ServerAdmin "webmaster@site2.com"
    ServerName site2.com
    ServerAlias www.site2.com
    MIMEMagicFile /dev/null
    CustomLog logs/site2.com_access_log "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\""
    ErrorLog logs/site2.com_error_log

    DocumentRoot "/home/site2/public_html" # <--------- Change this
    <Directory "/home/site2/public_html">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    Alias /usage "/home/site2/public_html/usage"
    <Location /usage>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Change the `DocumentRoot` of the second site to the same as the first

---

You can also set up a `symlink` with

```
ln -s /site1/public_html /site2/public_html
```

This will make `public_html` in site2 look to `/site1/public_html`

Comment: Can you really ssh into blogger.com? I wouldn't have thought so.