# Is it possible to have multiple subdomains point to the same Blogger blog?

Tags: dns, blogger

For our application we want to have a status page which is hosted outside of the rest of our infrastructure so in case there are issues in our data center we can post updates for our users and our users will be able to access them.

We registered a blog on Blogger and set it up with `xyzstatus.blogspot.com` and `status.xyz.com`. Everything seems to work fine.

We need to perform some maintenance at our datacenter which will sever all connectivity so we're unable to have a redirect using nginx or apache. We'd like to do this with a short TTL CNAME DNS entry.

Ideally `www.xyz.com` and `app.xyz.com` could be CNAMEd to `status.xyz.com`. When I setup the CNAME and go to that URL I get a Google broken robot 404 page. I figure I must need to let Google know it should associate traffic to `www.xyz.com` and `app.xyz.com` to the blog served up by `status.xyz.com`. But I can't see anywhere to do this in Blogger.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: It looks same as this http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20424/blogger-multiple-custom-domains

Comment: @elibyy You're correct that it looks similar except this is more on subdomains instead of completely separate domains. The link to Google tells you how to setup the CNAME but the issue is Blogger only seems to allow you to register one non-blogger sitename with each blogger instance and what I'm looking for again is multiple which this does cover unless I'm misreading it.

Comment: As far as I'm familiar with DNS it should work the same. I'm sorry but I don't have two domains and time to test it.